# Google API 0Auth2 cannot retrieve access token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am new to Google API. I have a script to import all mails into Google Groups but I cannot get the API to work.
I have my client_id, client_secret

then I used this link:
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[CLIENID]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.migration&response_type=code`
where I replaced the [CLIENDID] with my ClientID, I can authenticate and get back the AuthCode which I then used to run this command:
`curl --request POST --data "code=[AUTHCODE]&client_id=[CLIENTID]&client_secret=[CLIENTSECRET]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`
This works and shows me the refresh token, however, the script does say authentication failed. So I tried to run the command again and it says

> "error": "invalid_grant"

> "error_description": "Bad Request"

If I reopen the link above, get a new authcode and run the command again, it works but only for the first time. I am on a NPO Google Account and I activated the Trial Period.

Can anyone help me out here?

Complete script:

```
client_id="..."
client_secret="...."
refresh_token="......"

function usage() {
  (
    echo "usage: $0 <group-address> <mbox-dir>"
  ) >&2
  exit 5
}

GROUP="$1"
shift
MBOX_DIR="$1"
shift

[ -z "$GROUP" -o -z "$MBOX_DIR" ] && usage

token=$(curl -s --request POST --data "client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&refresh_token=$refresh_token&grant_type=refresh_token" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token | sed -n "s/^\s*\"access_token\":\s*\"\([^\"]*\)\",$/\1/p")

# create done folder if it doesn't already exist
DONE_FOLDER=$MBOX_DIR/../done
mkdir -p $DONE_FOLDER

i=0
for file in $MBOX_DIR/*; do
  echo "importing $file"
  response=$(curl -s -H"Authorization: Bearer $token" -H'Content-Type: message/rfc822' -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/groups/v1/groups/$GROUP/archive?uploadType=media" --data-binary @${file})
  result=$(echo $response | grep -c "SUCCESS")
  # check to see if it worked
  if [[ $result -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "upload failed on file $file.  please run command again to resume."
    exit 1
  fi

  # it worked!  move message to the done folder
  mv $file $DONE_FOLDER/

  ((i=i+1))
  if [[ $i -gt 9 ]]; then
    expires_in=$(curl -s "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=$token" | sed -n "s/^\s*\"expires_in\":\s*\([0-9]*\),$/\1/p")
    if [[ $expires_in -lt 300 ]]; then
      # refresh token
      echo "Refreshing token..."
      token=$(curl -s --request POST --data "client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&refresh_token=$refresh_token&grant_type=refresh_token" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token | sed -n "s/^\s*\"access_token\":\s*\"\([^\"]*\)\",$/\1/p")
    fi
    i=0
  fi
done
```

Comment: I wrote an article that shows how to implement Google OAuth 2 using `curl`. https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/

Comment: @JohnHanley Great, thanks a lot for sharing :)